# Different derivatives in image space and frequency space

Tags: image-processing, fft

I'm trying to compare between an image derivative obtained in the image space and the one obtained in the frequency space.
What I'm actually comparing is the magnitude of derivatives.

This is the process for image space:

1. calculate the x-derivative in image space by convolving the image with [1 -1] and get convDerX.
2. calculate the y-derivative in image space by convolving the image with [1;-1]  and get convDerY.
3. let convMagnitude =  sqrt(convDerX.^2 + convDerY.^2)

This is the process for frequency space:

1. calculate the Fourier transform of the image and derive by x, then invert back to image space to get fourDerX.
2. calculate the Fourier transform of the image and derive by y, then invert back to image space to get fourDerY.
3. let fourMagnitude =  sqrt(fourDerX.^2 + fourDerY.^2)

The two magnitudes are very similar, and show the edges, but they're not identical.
Why does this happen? Is it just due to discretization errors or is there something deeper here?

Comment: Well, just a thought but perhaps it might be of help. Convoluting with [1 -1] is not exactly the derivative, but only an approximation (for most uses it seems close enough).

Comment: One may try another approximation of 2nd order for derivative of C3 functions -- [-0.5,0,0.5] : result will differ from 1st order [-1,1] and it is ok, it is what "approximation" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In frequency space point value may depend on very image-distant points. So when you do such kind of FT manipulations it is like using multi-points scheme in image space, and for image-space convolution derivatives it is uncommon due to numerical instability. It is a stability-precision trade-off, so for typical non-rocket-science-problems 1st order of precision [-1,1] scheme or 2nd order [-0.5, 0, 0.5] is enough. Sure result for different schemes will differ a bit, as soon as we are in discrete world.

Comment: So you're implying that I could find an image that will give significantly different convolution and fourier derivatives? any generic way of creating such an image?

Comment: Not very significantly, due to meaning of "order of accuracy" term. Maximum difference usually exist near points with large function variation. Try black and white chessboard and you will see "significant" difference for different scheme derivatives in small image-space area near square edges (subtract one image from another).